# Cloud Firestore array_contains operator for queries

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to query a Cloud Firestore db based on substring matching. Regarding to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) it can be done with the `array_contains` operator.

```
> The where() method takes three parameters: a field to filter on, a
> comparison operation, and a value. The comparison can be <, <=, ==, >,
> >=, or array_contains
```

However when I try to use it, I get the following error:

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'full').where(u'desc', u'array_contains', snippet).get()
obj = doc_ref[0].to_dict()

ValueError: Operator string 'array_contains' is invalid. Valid choices are: <, <=, ==, >, >=.
```

At this point I don't know that the operator should be formatted differently, the docs is outdated or I just doing it wrong.

Comment: FYI array_contains is not "substring matching".  It's array presence matching.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of digging I found "Not supported yet" under the Python tab for the array_contains example.

[Python array_contains firestore docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJt6y.png)

Comment: it is definitely supported today:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#python